# In Facebook, is there a way to share images and posts across multiple people?

Tags: facebook, photo-sharing

My wife and I both have Facebook accounts and our friends overlap lets say 70%. So if we get back from a trip, she will post photos. I don't want to also upload and post photos as:

1. Then everyone in that 70% overlap will get two different posts
2. We are maintaining the set of pictures in two places (and takes twice as long to upload)

That being said, I do want to show these photos to my other 30% of people that don't overlap with her.

I see I can just share her post but then the 70% of photos still get "hit" twice.  What is the best way of managing this issue with out duplication?  This duplication is not the biggest deal in the world but I just wanted to see if there was a more elegant way of dealing with this.

Comment: create a custom list and share the pics with just the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try tagging yourself in the pictures, so you both your friends and hers can see the pictures. The best way to tackle it is by just adding the pictures on her Facebook (with privacy setting *Friends of friends*) and sharing it once on your wall.

Hope this helps you.